# Spring boot page loads slow

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have a fairly simple web application with a page for editing an entity.
It takes about 30 seconds to load and i don't see why. The SQL-queries finish in just over a second.

My controller method

```
@GetMapping(value = "/lasterapport/{id}")
public String lasterapport(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    model.addAttribute("lasterapport", lasterapportRepository.getOne(id));
    model.addAttribute("brukere", brukerRepository.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("lastere", maskinRepository.findLastere());
    model.addAttribute("trucker", maskinRepository.findTrucker());
    model.addAttribute("masser", masseRepository.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("destinasjoner", destinasjonRepository.findAll());
    return "lasterapport";
}
```

My entity (without getters and setters and constructor for readability)

```
@Entity
public class Lasterapport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Bruker truckBruker;

    @ManyToOne
    private Bruker lasterBruker;

    @ManyToOne
    private Maskin truckMaskin;

    @ManyToOne
    private Maskin lasterMaskin;

    @ManyToOne
    private Masse masse;

    @ManyToOne
    private Destinasjon destinasjon;

    private Integer tonn;
    private Date tidspunkt;
    private String vifte_id;
}
```

And my view is just a form with these select-inputs for all the different ManyToOne-relations

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="maskinLaster">Sjåfør laster</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{lasterBruker}">
                <option th:each="dropDownItem : ${brukere}"
                        th:value="${dropDownItem.id}"
                        th:text="${dropDownItem.navn}" >
                </option>
        </select>        
    </div>
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with how Spring handles the form data? Even if the queries are fairly quick, if i dont add the attributes that provides options for select-inputs the page finish loading almost instantly.

Comment: What about some logging line after line to find out how is the time consuming partitioned

Comment: The delay happens after the controller method returns. After that there's no breakpoints for me until the page displays.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this has been experienced before here: [Thymeleaf Select Option Performance Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911057/thymeleaf-select-option-performance-issue)

So my solution vas to not use **th:field** and the page loaded instantly.